# How to obtain block/slot time?

Tags: web3.js, jsonrpc-api

How to obtain block/slot time?

I know that I can view it [here](https://explorer.solana.com/) under the 1min and 1hr Slot Time average, but what I'm after is a way to request it directly via the Solana-web3js library or the JSON-RPC library. Is there a way?

Also I'm after the time it takes to process the block, not the block timestamp

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the RPC method `getRecentPerformanceSamples`: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getrecentperformancesamples

It gives a result like this:

```
[
    {
      "numSlots": 126,
      "numTransactions": 126,
      "samplePeriodSecs": 60,
      "slot": 348125
    },
    ...
]
```

So I think the 1 min calculation is that the slot time (in seconds) is `samplePeriodSecs/numSlots`

That API can return multiple samples (up to 720), so for example for the 1 hour average you could pass `limit=60`, do the above calculation for each sample and average them out.

Comment: samplePeriodSecs/numSlots = 60/126 = 476ms, or 2.1 slots per second.

Answer (score 0):

```
async function getBlockTime() {
  let absoluteSlot = (await connection.getEpochInfo()).absoluteSlot;
  return await connection.getBlockTime(absoluteSlot);
}
```